Why did Veronica deflect Alice's question?
In a heated exchange, the widows Veronica and Alice argue over Alice’s
swift move on with David, a real estate developer, after her husband’s
death. Alice defends David’s assistance in interpreting the blueprints
of the safe room. The argument reaches its peak when Veronica reveals
that the Mannings have killed Bash, who was Harry’s loyal chauffeur,
leaving Alice shocked.

Veronica : All this damage, I...I can't be responsible for all of it.
Alice: Why do you have to be?
Veronica: Because I don't own anything.

Here Alice asks "Why do you have to be?" responsible for all the damage.
Veronica responds by deflecting the question and stating "Because I don't
own anything." instead of addressing why she feels responsible.
Why did Veronica deflect Alice's question?

The deflection shows a mixed feeling of guilt and powerlessness. This statement is a way to express that she has a lack of control in that situation. Instead of controlling that situation, she seemed overwhelmed by the events happening and just went with the flow.
The deflection also suggests that maybe Veronica feels responsible for the damage even though no direct connection is there, it indicates that on a personal accountability or moral basis, she feels guilty.
Also, it seems like she is avoiding a direct confrontation with Alice about the event.
